# Como retornar ou extrair mais de um valor de uma função?

Tags: c, funções, return

```
integerPower( int y ){
    int base2;
    int base3;
    int base4;
    int total;

    base2 = pow( y , 2);
    base3 = pow( y, 3);
    base4 = pow( y, 4);
```

Quando eu chamo essa função (não digitei `return` porque é essa a dúvida) eu gostaria que as 3 bases fossem retornadas. A intenção é eu digitar um número como *input* e depois disso o programa iria chamar essa função e calcular com esse número sendo a base, no final eu quero que o *output* seja o meu numero digamos, base 2, calculado na potencia de 2, 3 e 4.

Tentei `return base2, base3, base4` e não deu certo. Por que isso não pode ser feito?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem alguma possibilidades para passar os dados de uma função para outra.

Uma simples é fazer "retornar" um *array* com os valores. Isso funciona se todos os valores retirados são do mesmo tipo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void integerPower(int y, int ret[4]) {
    ret[0] = pow(y, 2);
    ret[1] = pow(y, 3);
    ret[2] = pow(y, 4);
    ret[3] = ret[0] + ret[1] + ret[2];
}
int main(void) {
    int valores[4];
    integerPower(5, valores);
    printf("%d\n", valores[0]);
    printf("%d\n", valores[1]);
    printf("%d\n", valores[2]);
    printf("%d\n", valores[3]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/udGlA5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ReturnMatrixc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ReturnMatrix.c).

Também pode alocar no *heap* e retornar apenas o ponteiro para os valores. Não gosto da solução porque torna a alocação e liberação assimétrica, mas não deixa de ser uma alternativa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int *integerPower(int y) {
    int *ret = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    ret[0] = pow(y, 2);
    ret[1] = pow(y, 3);
    ret[2] = pow(y, 4);
    ret[3] = ret[0] + ret[1] + ret[2];
    return ret;
}
int main(void) {
    int *valores = integerPower(5);
    printf("%d\n", valores[0]);
    printf("%d\n", valores[1]);
    printf("%d\n", valores[2]);
    printf("%d\n", valores[3]);
    free(valores);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rPTgQ6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ReturnMatrix2c). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ReturnMatrix2.c).

Também pode só passar os valores como ponteiros, no final da execução as variáveis originais usadas como argumentos estarão com os valores desejados. Tem a vantagem de poder usar tipos heterogêneos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void integerPower(int y, int *base1, int *base2, int *base3, int *total) {
    *base1 = pow(y, 2);
    *base2 = pow(y, 3);
    *base3 = pow(y, 4);
    *total = *base1 + *base2 + *base3;
}
int main(void) {
    int base1, base2, base3, total;
    integerPower(5, &base1, &base2, &base3, &total);
    printf("%d\n", base1);
    printf("%d\n", base2);
    printf("%d\n", base3);
    printf("%d\n", total);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/a3uWE1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ReturnMatrix3c). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ReturnMatrix3.c).

E também pode ainda criar uma `struct` para retornar o os valores em um conjunto e com tipos heterogêneos. É um pouco mais burocrático e não compensa fazer se não for usar esta `struct` em outros lugares:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct integerPowerTuple {
    int base1;
    int base2;
    int base3;
    int total;
} IntegerPowerTuple;

IntegerPowerTuple integerPower(int y) {
    IntegerPowerTuple tupla = { pow(y, 2), pow(y, 3), pow(y, 4), tupla.base1 + tupla.base2 + tupla.base3 };
    return tupla;
}
int main(void) {
    IntegerPowerTuple tupla = integerPower(5);
    printf("%d\n", tupla.base1);
    printf("%d\n", tupla.base2);
    printf("%d\n", tupla.base3);
    printf("%d\n", tupla.total);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AHkj4S). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ReturnMatrix4c). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ReturnMatrix4.c).

Não é possível porque uma função só retorna um valor, isso é uma definição matemática e adotada pelas linguagens. É raro precisa retornar mais de um valor e se o fizer provavelmente eles estão muito vinculados entre si e provavelmente fazem parte de algo maior. Hoje tem linguagem que simulam essa possibilidade, mas são linguagens mais complexas por conta disto.