# Para que serve a vírgula?

Tags: c, c++, operadores, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

A vírgula é o que? Só uma construção da linguagem? Um operador? Por que ela existe?

Esta pergunta é baseada no que foi visto em [Como retornar ou extrair mais de um valor de uma função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171149/101).

```
return base2, base3, base4
```

Comment: Se fosse em Python, poderia se dizer que você está retornando uma `Tuple`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isso vale pra maioria das linguagens que foram baseadas nos mesmos princípios de sintaxe do C.

A vírgula é um operador que serve para separar e avaliar [expressões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101) podendo formar uma lista, que não deixa de ser uma expressão maior. Na verdade o operador é binário. Se tiver outras vírgulas o primeiro operando (esquerda) é o resultado da expressão anterior com duas expressões separadas por vírgula (algo como `((base2, base3), base4)`), que sempre será o resultado da última, não importa o que aconteça.

Um detalhe importante é que em uma lista o resultado dessa expressão maior (com todas as vírgulas) será sempre o valor resultante da última expressão da lista (sempre o mais à direita). Inclusive cada expressão pode até mesmo usar resultados das expressões anteriores se eles forem armazenados em variáveis. Claro que isto ocorre onde se espera um resultado.

Note que não é possível usar [*statements*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101), onde só o `;` pode separá-los, e eles não formam uma lista. Algumas expressões podem ser usadas como *statements* e pode parecer que elas são só *statements*, mas vale o fato de serem expressões.

É possível usar uma lista com itens separados por `,` em qualquer lugar que espera uma expressão. Então isto funciona:

```
int x = (1, 2, 3, 4); //o valor de x será 4, o resto seria apenas processado, mas não usado
```

Na prática muda nada, mas como o operador é binário isso é o mesmo que:

```
int x = (((1, 2), 3), 4); //neste exemplo específico os números anteriores foram ignorados
```

Claro que isto tem pouco utilidade. Fica interessante quando há expressões mais complexas e que geram efeitos colaterais, que você deveria evitar, mas funciona.

Um exemplo comum é em um `for`. Poucas pessoas sabem que podem ter várias expressões em cada parte dele. Um `for` espera três *statements*, um que normalmente é inicialização de variáveis, outro que é a condição de finalização do laço e o terceiro é o que deve ser executado ao fim de cada iteração do laço. Exemplo:

```
for (int x = 1, y = 1; x < 10 && y < 20; x++, y *= 2)
```

A condição poderia ter a vírgula também, mas neste caso faria mais sentido usar ambos. Se usasse o operador `,` apenas a última expressão booleana seria considerada para determinar se o laço terminaria ou não.

Um exemplo com condição:

```
if ((x = calcula(1, 2)), (y = x - 10), y > z)
```

Apenas o `y > z` determinará se entrará no `if`, mas as expressões anteriores são fundamentais para chegar nele. È feio, mas funciona.

Por isso que tentar retornar vários valores não dá certo, ele retorna só o último:

```
return 1, x, abs(x + 5), x * 2, x > 5;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Comma.c).

retornará 0 ou 1, porque só a expressão booleana será retornada, o resto será executado, mas descartado.

Pode estar pensando que uma chamada de uma função onde passa argumentos é diferente. Não é. É exatamente este operador que é usado ali para separar as expressões que formam os argumentos. Claro que ele não precisa fazer nada especial com a última expressão.

Podemos dizer o mesmo para um literal de *array*.

Curiosamente não vale para a lista de [parâmetros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) que usa a vírgula para separar *statements*, então deveria ser separado por `;`, talvez seja uma falha da sintaxe adotada por C.

Várias construções criativas podem ser feitas com este operador.

Só tem que tomar cuidado com [comportamento não especificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101) e não executar na ordem esperada.

Em C++ o operador pode ser sobrecarregado e mudar essa semântica, ainda que não deva.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: Não entendi : "Curiosamente não vale para a lista de parâmetros, talvez até por uma falha da sintaxe, afinal os parâmetros são statements e não expressões, então deveria ser separado por `;`" O que não vale para a lista de parâmetros ?

Comment: O uso da vírgula como um operador de avaliação de expressões. A vírgula ali é usada como se fosse um `;` e portanto não é o operador.

Comment: Não entendi nada do segundo parágrafo, poderia reformulá-lo, por favor? Não entendi o que é uma expressão anterior à mais à esquerda, nem o que é uma expressão com duas expressões separadas por vírgula, e nem o que seria o "resultado da última" nesse contexto.

Comment: @Piovezan tentei dar uma melhorada, não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: @Maniero Com o exemplo ficou mais fácil de visualizar, obrigado. Somente a frase _"resultado da última"_, esse _"a última"_ não sei a qual expressão se refere.

Comment: A última a ser executada, que é sempre a que está mais à direita, a última da lista, a que está depois da última vírgula.