# Incremento e decremento não funcionam na ordem esperada

Tags: c, operadores

```
int main(){
  int i=5;
  printf("%d%d%d%d%d",i++,i--,++i,--i,i);
}
```

> saída: 45555

Por que dessa saída? Não entendi corretamente a razão dessa saída.

Comment: para obter a saída com os incrementos e decrementos tem de dar em passos sequenciais

Comment: O problema é que como o @Maniero falou na resposta abaixo não há ordem garantida, mas também outro problema é que você está fazendo atribuição nessa variável, o correto seria fazer + 1 e - 1 para ter o resultado sem modificar o valor da variável, mas sem saber a utilização dessa instrução, não dá para ter certeza. Imagino que isso seja apenas um estudo de caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há garantias acerca da ordem de execução dos argumentos na chamada da função, portanto a intuição indica que fará nesta ordem e o resultado seria "56655", mas cada compilador pode fazer como achar melhor. Esta operação é considerada um [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101). Se deseja ordem faça um por *statement*, não use como expressões usando o [operador de lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175647/101) (vírgula).

Lembre-se que os operadores `++` e `--` são atribuidores, portanto produzem efeitos colaterais mudando o valor da variável. Se a intenção for adicionar ou subtrair 1 do valor da variável sem mudar o valor dela própria, aí tem que usar um operador que não faz atribuição, que não gere efeito colateral. No caso seria `i + 1` ou `i - 1`, assim geraria o resultado e o usaria sem afetar a variável. Neste caso o resultado seria "64645". Claro que seria semanticamente muito diferente do que postou, não parece querer saber isto.

Assim funciona como esperado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    printf("%d", i++);
    printf("%d", i--);
    printf("%d", ++i);
    printf("%d", --i);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9EfIsm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/taxuqiov-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/IncDecUndefined.c).