# Problemas com médias

Tags: c

Preciso inserir 3 notas, fazer a média com as 3 notas, depois com a maior nota e a segunda maior nota , depois com a maior nota e a pior nota.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int meio(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if(a>b && a<c)
    return a;
    else
    return b,c;
}
int menor (int a, int b, int c)
{
if (a<b && a<c)
return a;
else
return b,c;

}
int maior (int a, int b, int c)
{
if (a > b && a>c)
 return a;
else
 return b,c;  
}
main()
{
float M,MDM;
int n1,n2,n3;
printf("\n primeira nota: ");
scanf("%d",&n1);
printf("\n segunda nota: ");
scanf("%d",&n2);
printf("\n terceira nota: ");
scanf("%d",&n3);
printf("\n Maior nota = %d",maior(n1,n2,n3));
printf("\n Menor nota = %d",menor(n1,n2,n3));
printf("\n Segunda maior nota=%d",meio(n1,n2,n3));
M=(n1+n2+n3)/3;
printf("\n media:%.2f",M);
}
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dificuldade? Pois você inseriu seu código e o que deve ser feito mas não especificou em que empacou. Edite sua resposta para ficar mais detalhada de forma que então possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: então , eu não consigo separar a segunda maior nota , eu consigo a maior e a menor , mas não a segunda maior e eu preciso tirar média da maior e menor nota , da maior e da segunda maior e dps das 3 .

Comment: eu estava lá em cima tentando colocar como se fosse a segunda maior:int meio(int a, int b, int c)
{
 if(a>b && a<c)
 return a;
 else
 return b,c;
}

Comment: O que você acha que `return b,c;` iria fazer?

Comment: Já tentou ordenadar as três notas e então fazer `m=(a+b+c)/3;`, `x=(a+b)/2;`, `y=(a+c)/2;` e `z=(b+c)/2;`?

Comment: mas como o programa vai separar a média das maiores notas , e da maior com a menor ?

Comment: Ordenando as notas. Se a primeira for maior que a segunda, você troca a primeira com a segunda. Se a primeira for maior que a terceira, você troca a primeira com a terceira.  Se a segunda for maior que a terceira, você troca a segunda com a terceira.

Answer (score 0):

No comando `return b, c;`, o [operador vírgula](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175647/para-que-serve-a-v%C3%ADrgula) retorna apenas o último elemento separado pela vírgula, e por isso não tem um sentido lógico no seu programa. Por exemplo, na função `maior`, ao invés de ser `return b, c;`, deveria ser calculado o maior entre os dois.

```
int maior (int a, int b, int c){
    if (a > b && a > c) return a;
    if (b > a && b > c) return b;
    return c;   
}
```

Utilize a mesma lógica para as funções `menor` e `meio` e seu programa irá funcionar.

Comment: caracaaaa , vlwww manoo !!! agora foi , agora só tenho que pensar em como fazer a média , mas já ajudou muito ! muito obrigado !

Comment: Você já conseguiu calcular a média das três notas, usando `M = (n1+n2+n3)/3;`. Como a média entre duas notas é a soma das notas dividido por 2, e você já tem como pegar o valor da maior nota e a pior nota (ou seja, chamando a função `maior` e `menor`), é só usar o mesmo procedimento.

Comment: eu sei como colocar no printf , mas não sei colocar como formula , pq quando eu coloco como formula eu só consigo organizar MeM=(n1+n2)/2

Comment: no printf eu sei que no final eu tenho que colocar -> ("...",menor (n1,n2,n3),maior(n1,n2,n3));

Comment: Você pode armazenar o valor da função numa variável, por exemplo, `maiorNota = maior(n1, n2, n3);`, criar outras variáveis para a menor nota e para a nota do meio e usá-las então na fórmula da média.

Comment: mano , funcionou perfeitamente! nem sei como te agradecer , to tendo muita dificuldade para aprender programação , fiquei um tempo sem praticar pq meu notebook deu problema ai acabei me embolando na matéria. Mas mttt obrigado e desculpa por qualquer coisa !