# Queria aprender sobre o operador "," na linguagem C e C++?

Tags: c, c++, operadores

vou coloca o exemplo de um código que vi abaixo:

```
while(scanf("%d %d %d %d", &h, &u, &d, &f), h) {...

}
```

a entrada parava quando h recebia valor 0.

Comment: Existe o **[operador vírgula](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175647/69296)**. No exemplo da pergunta, a vírgula é utilizada em duas situações: como o separador dos argumentos na lista de aplicação da função e como o próprio operador (já linkado no início deste comentário).

Comment: @LuizFelipe Se entendi pelo que ele disse na pergunta ele se refere a vírgula fora dos argumentos passados, se refere ao `, h`, claro que o resultado do h é determinado pelo que é passado no scanf.

Comment: O operador é o mesmo, não importa onde seja usado, o local pode mudar aspectos específicos. Se tiver uma pergunta mais específica sobre essa situação aí é diferente, e faltaria clareza sobre oque está pergunta, a pergunta precisaria ser reformulada.