# Por que uma atribuição cujo valor usa o operador vírgula nem sempre resulta na expressão mais à direita?

Tags: c, característica-linguagem, operadores, sintaxe

Estou com uma dúvida sobre o operador vírgula em C.

No código abaixo, levando em conta alguns textos que li (1) e (2) e vendo a resposta postada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175647/para-que-serve-a-v%c3%adrgula), eu esperava que o valor de `c` seria 20 (expressão mais à direita) e não 10 (expressão à esquerda). O valor de `d` é 20, conforme esperado.

```
int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    c = a, b;       // c = 10
    d = (a, b);     // d = 20
    return 0;
}
```

Também tentei fazer a atribuição conforme indicada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175647/para-que-serve-a-v%C3%ADrgula)  e obtive o erro "**expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant**"

```
int x = 1, 2, 3, 4; //expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
```

O programa foi compilado com o gcc 9.4.0.

- Onde está o meu erro?
- Meu erro estaria na questão da precedência do operador de atribuição, que é maior que a do operador de vírgula?
- Qual a razão do erro na atribuição de "x"?

> (1) "Considere a expressão e1, e2. O tipo e o valor da expressão são o
> tipo e o valor de e2; o resultado da avaliação de e1 é descartado. O
> resultado será um valor l se o operando à direita for um valor l." -
> ([Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/cpp/comma-operator?view=msvc-170))

> (2) "As vírgulas usadas aqui [exemplo de uso de for], na realidade são
> operadores de vírgula, que garantem que as listas de expressões sejam
> avaliadas da esquerda para a direita. O valor e o tipo de uma lista
> separada por vírgulas são o valor e o tipo da expressão mais à direita
> na lista" (Deitel, p. 83, C: como programar)

Comment: De fato, faltou parênteses lá, está corrigido agora, me desculpe pela falha e obrigado por perceber isso, mostra que foi útil para você e responde para pessoas como você. E o hkotsubo já respondeu bem que no contexto a precedência cria o problema, em outros contextos não tem esse problema. Mesmo colocando os parênteses é possível que algum compilador, ou configuração gere *warning*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para entender a diferença, basta analisarmos a [AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) que cada uma das declarações gera.

No caso, usei o clang (versão 10.0.0-4ubuntu1), com as seguintes opções:

```bash
clang teste.c -Xclang -ast-dump
```

Com isso ele mostra toda a AST, mas vamos ver especificamente a atribuição da variável `c`:

```
|-BinaryOperator 0x12b19c0 <line:11:5, col:12> 'int' ','
| |-BinaryOperator 0x12b1968 <col:5, col:9> 'int' '='
| | |-DeclRefExpr 0x12b1910 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0x12b1728 'c' 'int'
| | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x12b1950 <col:9> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
| |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x12b1930 <col:9> 'int' lvalue Var 0x12b1628 'a' 'int'
| `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x12b19a8 <col:12> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
|   `-DeclRefExpr 0x12b1988 <col:12> 'int' lvalue Var 0x12b16a8 'b' 'int'
```

Ou seja, o operador vírgula tem dois operandos: a atribuição `c = a` e a expressão `b` (que neste caso não faz nada, é como se eu tivesse uma linha contendo somente `b;`, que é uma expressão válida, mas sem efeito algum). Ou seja, `c = a` e `b` são duas expressões separadas. O operador vírgula continua agindo, mas `c = a` é o primeiro operando, então ele executa primeiro (atribuindo o valor de `a` em `c`), e depois ele "executa `b`" (mas como é uma expressão sem efeito, não "acontece nada").

No fundo, essa expressão é interpretada como `(c = a), b`, já que o [operador `=` tem precedência maior que o operador `,`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). A expressão equivale à árvore abaixo:

[image: operador = tem precedência sobre vírgula]

Caso a imagem não carregue:

```
        +-----+
        |  ,  |
        +-----+
        /     \
       /       \
    +-----+  +-----+
    |  =  |  |  b  |
    +-----+  +-----+
    /     \
   /       \
+-----+  +-----+
|  c  |  |  a  |
+-----+  +-----+
```

---

Agora a atribuição da variável `d` é diferente:

```
|-BinaryOperator 0x12b1ab0 <line:12:5, col:14> 'int' '='
| |-DeclRefExpr 0x12b19e0 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0x12b17a8 'd' 'int'
| `-ParenExpr 0x12b1a90 <col:9, col:14> 'int'
|   `-BinaryOperator 0x12b1a70 <col:10, col:13> 'int' ','
|     |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x12b1a40 <col:10> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
|     | `-DeclRefExpr 0x12b1a00 <col:10> 'int' lvalue Var 0x12b1628 'a' 'int'
|     `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x12b1a58 <col:13> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
|       `-DeclRefExpr 0x12b1a20 <col:13> 'int' lvalue Var 0x12b16a8 'b' 'int'
```

Veja que agora, por causa dos parênteses, a expressão `(a, b)` é avaliada primeiro, e só depois o seu valor é atribuído a `d`. Isso porque no início temos o operador de atribuição (`=`) com dois operandos: a variável `d` e o resultado do operador `,` – e este, por sua vez, tem dois operandos: `a` e `b`.

No caso, a expressão equivale à árvore abaixo:

[image: com parênteses, operador vírgula é executado primeiro]

Caso a imagem não carregue:

```
        +-----+
        |  =  |
        +-----+
        /     \
       /       \
    +-----+  +-----+
    |  d  |  |  ,  |
    +-----+  +-----+
             /     \
            /       \
         +-----+  +-----+
         |  a  |  |  b  |
         +-----+  +-----+
```

---

## Por que `int x = 1, 2, 3, 4;` não compila?

Quanto ao caso citado, de `int x = 1, 2, 3, 4;` não compilar, vamos fazer alguns testes para entender. Fiz os exemplos abaixo com somente dois valores, para simplificar, mas a ideia é a mesma.

Primeiro vamos testar com:

```c
int x = 1, 2;
```

Compilando tanto com gcc 9.4.0 e clang 10.0.0-4ubuntu1, dá erro:

```bash
$ gcc teste.c
teste.c: In function ‘main’:
teste.c:7:16: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
    7 |     int x = 1, 2;
```

```bash
$ clang teste.c -Xclang -ast-dump
teste.c:7:16: error: expected identifier or '('
    int x = 1, 2;
               ^
teste.c:7:15: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    int x = 1, 2;
```

No caso do clang, ele também mostra a AST que conseguiu montar:

```
|-DeclStmt 0x14dafb0 <line:7:5, col:16>
| `-VarDecl 0x14daf28 <col:5, col:13> col:9 x 'int' cinit
|   `-IntegerLiteral 0x14daf90 <col:13> 'int' 1
`-ReturnStmt 0x14dafe8 <line:15:5, col:12>
  `-IntegerLiteral 0x14dafc8 <col:12> 'int' 0
```

Repare que ele interpreta isso como um `DeclStmt` (*declaration statement*), ou seja, uma declaração de variável (no caso, `x`), cujo valor atribuído é `1`. O `2` não consegue ser interpretado corretamente: repare que o próximo item da AST já é o `return 0;`, que no meu programa era a próxima linha.

Isso é porque em um *declaration statement* a vírgula serve para separar as declarações de duas ou mais variáveis - por exemplo, `int a, b, c;` ou `int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;` ou ainda `int a = 1, b, c = 3;` (`a` e `c` são declaradas e já inicializadas, `b` é somente declarada). **Neste caso, a vírgula não é o operador, e sim um separador de declarações de variáveis**.

Ou seja, ali ele estava esperando um identificador (no caso, um nome de variável), daí a mensagem "*expected identifier*". Mas como `2` é um literal numérico, e não um identificador válido, dá erro de compilação.

---

Por outro lado, se adicionarmos os parênteses:

```c
int x = (1, 2);
```

Agora ambos (gcc e clang) compilam, e podemos ver na AST que a expressão entre parênteses é executada primeiro, e só depois o seu valor é atribuído a `x`:

```
|-DeclStmt 0x23f2010 <line:7:5, col:19>
| `-VarDecl 0x23f1f28 <col:5, col:18> col:9 x 'int' cinit
|   `-ParenExpr 0x23f1ff0 <col:13, col:18> 'int'
|     `-BinaryOperator 0x23f1fd0 <col:14, col:17> 'int' ','
|       |-IntegerLiteral 0x23f1f90 <col:14> 'int' 1
|       `-IntegerLiteral 0x23f1fb0 <col:17> 'int' 2
```

Pois agora é uma declaração de variável, cujo valor atribuído é o resultado da expressão entre parênteses.

---

Mas isso só acontece se estivermos declarando e atribuindo a variável ao mesmo tempo. Curiosamente, se separarmos a declaração da atribuição, aí o código compila e executa:

```c
int x;
x = 1, 2;
```

Pois como já explicado acima, agora a segunda linha não é mais uma declaração, e sim uma operação. Mas como o operador vírgula tem menor prioridade, a atribuição `x = 1` é executada primeiro:

```
|-DeclStmt 0x2407100 <line:7:5, col:10>
| `-VarDecl 0x2407098 <col:5, col:9> col:9 used x 'int'
|-BinaryOperator 0x2407198 <line:8:5, col:12> 'int' ','
| |-BinaryOperator 0x2407158 <col:5, col:9> 'int' '='
| | |-DeclRefExpr 0x2407118 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0x2407098 'x' 'int'
| | `-IntegerLiteral 0x2407138 <col:9> 'int' 1
| `-IntegerLiteral 0x2407178 <col:12> 'int' 2
```

E agora o `2` é interpretado como um literal numérico (`IntegerLiteral`), pois neste caso a segunda linha não é mais uma declaração de variável (que espera um identificador), e sim o operador vírgula, que aceita qualquer expressão válida.

E como já explicado acima, o segundo operando (o literal numérico `2`) acaba não tendo nenhum efeito aqui. Curiosamente, se compilarmos com a opção `-Wall`, é mostrado o *warning* que diz justamente isso (a mensagem do gcc é mais específica):

```bash
$ gcc -Wall teste.c
teste.c: In function ‘main’:
teste.c:8:10: warning: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    8 |     x = 1, 2;

$ clang -Wall teste.c
teste.c:8:12: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
```

---

Por fim, só para deixar completo, podemos separar a declaração da atribuição e incluir os parênteses:

```c
int x;
x = (1, 2);
```

Isso gera a AST:

```
|-DeclStmt 0xd5b100 <line:7:5, col:10>
| `-VarDecl 0xd5b098 <col:5, col:9> col:9 used x 'int'
|-BinaryOperator 0xd5b1b8 <line:8:5, col:14> 'int' '='
| |-DeclRefExpr 0xd5b118 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0xd5b098 'x' 'int'
| `-ParenExpr 0xd5b198 <col:9, col:14> 'int'
|   `-BinaryOperator 0xd5b178 <col:10, col:13> 'int' ','
|     |-IntegerLiteral 0xd5b138 <col:10> 'int' 1
|     `-IntegerLiteral 0xd5b158 <col:13> 'int' 2
```

Que faz com que o operador vírgula seja executado primeiro, e o seu resultado (no caso, `2`) seja atribuído a `x`.